# Quotient rings (modules) of a bigger ideal is contained in the quotient ring (modules) of a smaller ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have a question about rings and then about general modules. Suppose $R$ is a ring and $I$, $J$ are proper ideals of $R$ such that $J\subset I$. Then my first question is “is $R/I\subset R/J$ as quotient rings?” What about as submodules? I.e. is $R/I$ a $R$-submodule of $R/J$?

Comment: Intuitively I think this holds, but I can't come up with a rigorous proof hence, I can't really convince myself with just my intuition.

Comment: $R/I$ is a set of equivalence classes mod $I$ and $R/J$ of equivalence classes mod $J$, so they're not the same. For instance, $I\in R/I$ and if $I\in R/J$, then $I=J$. So unless $I=J$, there is no such inclusion

Comment: @Max Thank you! What if I am working with a PID and that let $I$ = $(d)$, $d$ $\in$ $R$, $d$ = ${p_1}^{e_1}...{p_n}^{e_n}$, and let J = $({p_i}^{e_i})$?

Comment: There actually is a mapping, but it goes in the other direction. See if you can construct it. Notice that if $a\equiv b \mod J$ then automatically $a\equiv b \mod I$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $R/I$ cannot be in general identified with a subring of $R/J$.

Consider the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=6\mathbb{Z}$. Then $R/I$ and $R/J$ are the rings of residue classes modulo $2$ and $6$ respectively, which have no proper subring.

What's generally true is that $R/I$ is a *quotient ring* of $R/J$, which is precisely the statement of the third (but the numbering depends on the textbook) homomorphism theorem: in this case $I/J$ is an ideal in $R/J$ and the quotient ring $(R/J)/(I/J)$ is isomorphic to $R/I$.

The same goes for the module case. The example $\mathbb{Z}$ can be misleading, because in the case of a PID, the quotient $R/I$ is *isomorphic to* a submodule of $R/J$ (use uniqueness of factorization). But in general this does not happen.